# How do google translate, bing translate etc. for websites work?

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

I wonder how google translate, bing translate etc. work when translating a webpage. How is it possible to manipulate text on external websites (e.g., English text -> French text), as these translators do?
Do they copy the whole webpage on their own server (e.g., google) prior to that manipulation?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a question - what does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Why don't you google Google? Or bing Bing?

Comment: That's a great and interesting question, but stackoverflow is for concrete very tangible questions where you already have a clue how to roughly do things.

Answer (score 0):

Also the question is a lot easier than you think, if you think about a website as html, simply replacing text with a translation of that text will give you a html with the same layout than the website you're translating, so you're making it more complex than necessary in your mind.